# Federated user can't be found in the ad user directory

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

We are trying to block the federated user from azure ad b2c custom policies.

following the sample from https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/disable-social-account-from-logon

Issue:

When running the custom policies with our saml assertion from samples, when the federated user is logged in from the external IDP below page is triggered

[The page after signin of federated user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSP7j.png) with the output claim of federated user details.

B2C URL: https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase/samlp/sso/assertionconsumer

I need to skip this page and make silent signup of user to generated objectid ad b2c using AAD-CreateAlternativeSecurityId technical profile.

Issue 2:
Even with this page when I press continue, it throws an error "Unable to validate the information provided." not sure about this validation and how to overcome this error ?

In short, I need help on how to create a federated user in azure ad b2c automatically from the custom policies during signin and update extended user attributes for the federated user.

Comment: `unable to find the user information in the azure ad b2c tenant` -> do you mean in the Azure Portal? `only smal assertions output claims are displayed.` -> specifically what and where? and what are you expecting to see? what is `azure ad b2c users list`? Is that in the Azure Portal? If the users are being created, then you don't need to recreate them.

Comment: my bad in explaining, Updated the question now @JasSuri-MSFT can you suggest, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove the orchestration step which references the `SelfAsserted-Social` technical profile. This technical profile will ask the user to provide more information (displayName, givenName, surName) after sign up with a Social Account.

If these claims are mapped appropriately with the social account technical profile, then they will just get written to the directory in a later step by default.

To troubleshoot your policy, follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#see-the-logs-in-vs-code-extension).

Comment: Yes, I tried to remove the orchestration step which referred to the SelfAsserted-Social technical profile and got the below error message:

AADB2C90037: An error occurred while processing the request. Please contact administrator of the site you are trying to access.